# What to do with the problem NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When testing the game in the console, this error appears and points to one of the scripts (I will attach below). The error refers to a specific line of code (for example, money Text.text = money.toString();)

```
public void Start()
{
    money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Money");
    earnedMoney = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("earnedMoney");
    record = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("record");
    live = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("live");
    money += earnedMoney;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Money", money);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 0);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("earnedMoney", 0);
    moneyText.text = money.ToString();
    recordText.text = record.ToString();
    liveText.text = live.ToString();
}
```

If you put it below in the start method, the error will refer to another similar line that turned out to be the "highest" (For example, liveText.text = live.ToString();). Can you tell me how to fix this ?

```
    public void Start()
    {
        money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Money");
        earnedMoney = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("earnedMoney");
        record = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("record");
        live = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("live");
        money += earnedMoney;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Money", money);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 0);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("earnedMoney", 0);
        liveText.text = live.ToString();
        moneyText.text = money.ToString();
        recordText.text = record.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: It means that your liveText, moneyText, etc. variables are not assigned. So the short answer is "make sure that your variable is not null before trying to use it"

Comment: `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Money", money);` there are much cleaner, more idiomatic, less wordy, more OOP ways of accessing class data.  Research the wonderful world of *Properties*-

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp what are you talking about? o.O [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) are mainly used for storing values persistently across sessions ... OP here is loading and resetting them on app start - not something you will be resolving using properties and OOP ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a class maybe withoud instance, or you are working with an object which is null and the exception will be thrown because you are trying to work with a method and null variable does not have any method.

**I think the problem is for money variable, set breakpoint on it and that would be null.**

Comment: I do not know how to do "set breakpoint on it and that would be null.". can you write an example please?

Comment: break point would interupt the process for debugging
on the left side of the line of code is a coulumn and if you click on it a red small circle will be appear , and you should run your code in debug mode,
by the way, are you using Visual studio ?

Comment: How do I make a break point ?

Comment: message edited.

Comment: VSCODE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/media/debugging-with-visual-studio-code/breakpoint-set-net6.png

Microsoft visual studio:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/media/vs-2022/dbg-tour-set-a-breakpoint.png?view=vs-2022

Comment: the error continues to refer to the line with "break point". And I just realized something else, this error indicates a creak in the "menu" scene, but the error does not appear when loading the "menu" scene, it appears when loading another "Shop" scene. Maybe this will show the problem. Yes i use Visual Studio

Comment: You should check in debugging which one of your objects is null.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour

Comment: `money ` is an `int` .. it can't be `null` ever ;) it is probably rather the `moneyText` ;)